# How to share one ethernet cable between two devices with high speed?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have two devices, a PS4 and a Raspberry pi that I'd like to connect to the internet hub through ethernet. The hub is 20m away from the devices by cable, so running two cables isn't suitable. I'd like to use one cable. The raspberry pi is to be used for streaming both video and game, so requires high bandwidth. The PS4 might stream but will mostly be used from playing online. Only one device will be in use at a time. It seems an ethernet splitter would split the wire and reduce bandwidth. Is there a device that could switch between the two devices automatically?

Comment: You need another hub/switch. Single wire between hubs, 2 to devices.

Comment: 100Mbit Ethernet *technically* only needs 2 pairs, so potentially you could split a 4 pair cable out into 2 Ethernet cables, but you would still need two ports available on your hub.

Comment: You can't split an Ethernet cable in such a way as to share pins between 3 endpoints - doing this will cause imbalences in the line which will greatly retard performance.

Comment: *"Is there a device that could switch between the two devices automatically?"* -- Yes, and it's called an Ethernet switch.  BTW Ethernet "hub" is obsolete; they haven't been sold for about 15 years, and the fastest was 10Base-T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is an ethernet switch/bridge. It is a device that connects layer 2 network with each other. Most routers today have one built in allready (about the last sesible integration that has found their way into routers). You need a switch, a long cable running to the router and shorter ones to connect all the devices mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a power socket nearby, I think your best option is a powerline, with two ethernet ports.

[What is powerline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication)?

```
Power-line communication (PLC) is a communication method that uses electrical 
wiring to simultaneously carry both data and electric power. It is also known 
as power-line carrier, power-line digital subscriber line (PDSL), mains 
communication, power-line telecommunications, or power-line networking (PLN).
```

[image]

Comment: I've heard powerline won't have as high a bandwidth as I need to stream games.

Comment: Don't dismiss it until you have tried it. Most games do not require that high a bandwidth (as most Internet connections are not that fast). What they do require is low latency, and powerline can sometimes for a better job of this then wifi.

Comment: There are videos online that you can max 100mbps line, with the right powerline. I don't think you will need more than 100mbps to stream your games.

Comment: Powerlin is the biggest pos I have seen in a long while! On my router I get 1 Gb/s symetrical. My powerline, whiche is rated for 1 Gb/s, delivers like 150 up and 5 down. And that is not the only setup like that I know and tend to. Not to mention that the pairing craps out every now and then. Really, its your worst option. If you don't have to drill holes through 7 walls, use a nice Cat5e or Cat6 cable.  Powerline is a nasty hack, and it performs like one.

Comment: @paradoxon because something didn't work for you it doesn't mean it doesn't work for anybody else.

Comment: @Sonamor I have tested about 10 situation in different houses, for different customers and relatives. It just does not deliver what it claims. And if you look at the engineering basics which it uses (which I happen to understand somwhat) you will see that it is a nasty hack.

Comment: I can say the same for 10 relatives and customers of mine that this is working. Also companies do not build products based on nasty hacks neither Protocols are being build on them.

Comment: Companies don't care if something just barely works or if it is a fine engineering solution. As long as there is money in it they will sell you pigeon poop as whipped cream. Ever wondered why serious networking companies never touch powerline? I mean the electrical in many places barley even cuts it for power delivery and then powerline tries to run highly modulated, high frequency signal through that unshielded mess? In my opinion this is begging for trouble. It might be fine for web surfing, but anything more serious - no.

Comment: I think you can only use one powerline pair per house/apartment. That means if you have multiple devices spread throughout, then they can't all be using powerline. (That would be too convenient, LOL!)

Comment: You can add more powerline adapters in the same network as long as they are compatible to each other.